# Combining Thunderbolt ports

Tags: display, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I've a Macbook Pro retina 15'', mid-2012 with nVidia 650M graphics card. I've a 4K Dell monitor attached but the result is a bit choppy and my guess is that it's because of the bandwidth limitation on the Thunderbolt port?

If so, can I somehow combine both thunderbolt ports and connect the external to both together?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your computer has a "Thunderbolt 1" port. Apple states in [this FAQ article on thunderbolt ports](http://support.apple.com/us-en/HT5219#25) as an answer to question #25:

> 4K Ultra HD TVs are supported over HDMI or with Thunderbolt to
>   high-speed HDMI adapters. Thunderbolt 2 is required to use a 4K
>   display. All Thunderbolt 2 models support 4K displays at 30Hz in
>   Single Stream Transport mode. Some models support 4K displays at 60 Hz
>   in Multi Stream Transport mode. See HT6008 for more information on
>   using 4K displays. Specific 4K DisplayPort displays are supported on
>   Thunderbolt with a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that and I can run the 4K -- just the result is not as smooth as I'd like. That's why I was wondering if there was a way to combine the two ports to get higher bandwidth

Comment: @Opt No you can't, you need a Thunderbolt 2 port to run 4K smoothly.